# I need store set of object in firebase using one request with firebase unique key .(without array index as a key)

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need store set of object in firebase using one request with firebase unique key .(without array index as a key)

```
let object_list =  {
  '0': {
    'title':'title 1',
    'time':'12.30pm',
  },
  '1': {
    'title':'title 2',
    'time':'12.30pm',
  },
  '2': {
    'title':'title 3',
    'time':'12.30pm',
  },
}

this.agendaRef = firebase.database().ref('objs/');
let data = this.agendaRef.push();
data.set(object_list);
```

I expect the output

```
 -LioB1b06T7tfVhbJmss6o
    time: "12.30pm"
    title:"title 1"

 -LioB1b06T7tfVhbsdfsdf
    time: "12.30pm"
    title:"title 2"

 -LioB1b06Tsdsdsd7tfVh2
    time: "12.30pm"
    title: "title 3"
```

but the actual output is

```
 -LioB1b06T7tfVhbJm6o
 0
    time: "12.30pm"
    title:"title 1"
 1
    time: "12.30pm"
    title:"title 2"
 2
    time: "12.30pm"
    title: "title 3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Each call to `push` generates a single ID. So if you want multiple generated IDs, you'll need to call `push` multiple times.

A key thing to realize is that calling `push()` without any arguments is a client-side only operation. So you can call `push()` three times to generate the IDs, and still only perform a single write operation, with something like this:

```
let object_list =  [
  {
    'title':'title 1',
    'time':'12.30pm',
  },
  {
    'title':'title 2',
    'time':'12.30pm',
  },
  {
    'title':'title 3',
    'time':'12.30pm',
  }
}]

this.agendaRef = firebase.database().ref('objs/');

let object = {};
object_list.forEach((value) => {
  object[this.agendaRef.push().key] = value;
})

data.set(object);
```